# Receiving heap-buffer-overflow for the following code snippet

Tags: arrays, c, buffer-overflow, heap-corruption

**Below is the code:**

```
/* Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free() */

int* twoSum (int* numbers, int numbersSize, int target, int* returnSize)
{
    int i, j;
    j = numbersSize;
    i = 0;
    
    while(numbers[j] > target) j--;
    
    int k;
    while(i < j) {
        k = j;
        while(i < k) {
            if(target - numbers[j] == numbers[i])
                break;
            j--;
        }
        i++;
    }
    
    int *idx = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
    idx[0] = i;
    idx[1] = j;
    
    *returnSize = 2;
    
    return idx;
}
```

**Receiving the following error**:

```
=================================================================
==31==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000020 at pc 0x55d94f9cf8a3 bp 0x7ffea0179340 sp 0x7ffea0179330
READ of size 4 at 0x602000000020 thread T0
    #2 0x7f77ad9180b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
0x602000000020 is located 0 bytes to the right of 16-byte region [0x602000000010,0x602000000020)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f77ae55dbc8 in malloc (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10dbc8)
    #3 0x7f77ad9180b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c047fff7fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c047fff8000: fa fa 00 00[fa]fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8010: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==31==ABORTING
```

I don't see any error here, as i made returnSize as 2. The size of returned array(idx) is also 2 i.e., sizeof(int) * 2. Also, any information about the core dump would be appreciated.

I got this error while solving a two pointer problem on leetcode.

**Update**: Error resolved, working solution.

```
/* Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free(). */
int* twoSum(int* numbers, int numbersSize, int target, int* returnSize){
    int i, j;
    j = numbersSize-1;
    i = 0;
    
    if(numbersSize == 0 || numbers == NULL)
        return NULL;
    
    while(numbers[j] > target)  j--;
    
    int k;
    while(i < j) {
        k = j;
        while(i < k) {
            if(target - numbers[k] == numbers[i])
                break;
            k--;
        }
        
        if(i >= k)
            i++;
        else
            break;
    }
    
    if(i >= j)
        return NULL;
    
    int *idx = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
    idx[0] = i;
    idx[1] = j;
    
    *returnSize = 2;
    
    return idx;
}
```

**Update: Optimized Solution**

```
/**
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */
int* twoSum(int* numbers, int numbersSize, int target, int* returnSize){
    int i, j;
    i = 0;
    j = numbersSize - 1;
    
    while(numbers[i] + numbers[j] != target) {
        if(numbers[i] + numbers[j] < target)    i++;
        else    j--;
    }
    
    int *idx = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
    idx[0] = i+1;
    idx[1] = j+1;
    *returnSize = 2;
    
    return idx;
}
```

Comment: If you have an array `arr` of size `N`, what is `arr[N]`?

Comment: Is `numbersSize` the number of elements in the `numbers` array, or the top index? Those are two different things.

Comment: Understood your point @Passerby, but the caller has to take care of it as we are supposed to set returnSize to the size of the array but not the highest index of the array.

Comment: Also, none of your loop does any kind of bounds checking. What if there's no element in `numbers` for which `numbers[k] > target` will be true? What if `target - numbers[j] == numbers[i]` never becomes true?

Comment: If the second argument is the array size, you have a bug, and if it is not the array size, then you have a bad name. Something must be fixed either way.

Comment: @harish The code has `j = numbersSize;` followed later by `while (numbers[j] ...`, so you have to "take care of it". The error message has nothing to do with the `malloc` or anything after the `malloc`.

Comment: `while(numbers[j] > target) j--;` but j is initialized to `numbersSize`.  Either index with j - 1 or initialize `j = NumbersSize - 1`, and if that condition doesn't go false before `j == 0` then it will underflow the numbers array.

Comment: `while(i < k)` How do you ensure that `j--` does not underflow?

Comment: Thanks everyone. Updated the code, available in the description.